How can i calculate total hours in a day between multiple workers hours
I have a table named worker_table which entains worker_name, timeIn and timeOut. The total worked hour in the table is 3hours while the total payment is $34.44
enter image description here
My question is How can I calculate total hours and payment in a day between multiple workers hour
This is the result I get.
enter image description here
The result I want is the total worked hour and payment which is
3hours and $34.44
My code below can only calculate a single row worked hour.
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM worker_table ");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        $from_time = strtotime($row['timeIn']);
        $to_time = strtotime($row['timeOut']);
        $diff_minutes = round(abs($from_time - $to_time) / 60, 2);

        $hours = intdiv($diff_minutes, 60) . ':' . ($diff_minutes % 60);

        echo $hours . "<br><br>";
    }

Please I really don't know what to do. Your help will be very important to me.
Thank you.

"This is the result I get." - if you want to get those values shown there summed up - then you should add up the $diff_minutes in your loop, and output the formatted result after the loop.

You can use a grouping function, like this: SELECT SUM(payment) AS total_payment FROM worker_table. Note that when you expand your database you may need to use a GROUP BY. Note that the result of this query is different from the current query you have in your question.

I would prefer to use Mysql instead of looping through PHP for me it is simple and I don't have to spent time on building unnecessary logic
$sql = "SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(`timeOut`, `timeIn`)))) AS total_worked_hours, SUM(`payment`) AS total_payment FROM `worker_table`";
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$total_hours = $row['total_worked_hours'];
$total_payment = $row['total_payment'];

